# How can I discover a maximised window's restored position co-ordinates?

Tags: autohotkey

As the title suggests, I'm trying to discover where a maximised parent window will be re-drawn when the user Restores it from a maximised state.  Now, I can currently do this by using the winRestore command, capture the position and then winMaximise again, but this causes the window to a) flash as it is drawn twice and b) takes too long for a process that I want to be instant to the user (I use the Restored position later when moving the window to another screen).

I'm fairly sure I'm on the right path with the GetWindowsPlacement Windows API method, but I'm willing to admit that figuring out how to get the info I need is a step beyond my current dllCalling coding abilities and Google searches aren't turning up anything.

In a nutshell: what I want to be able to do is get and set (into the Windows window management system) the top-left co-ordinate of any window's Restored position without actually redrawing and moving the maximised window.

Does anyone have a direction or pointer I can follow?  Thanks!

Comment: What is your use case? Maybe there's another way to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: I want to enhance a simple "move window to next screen" function.  This is easy to do if a window isn't maximised (X-pos + screenwidth = new X-pos) but sending a maximised window across screens doesn't also move its restored position and I'm trying to discover where it would restore to while avoiding the flashes of window draw involved in using winRestore-move-winMaximise, and then manipulate the stack so that the window will restore to the new monitor directly.  I tried making the window transparent before restoring-moving-maxing, but it's too slow.

Comment: Cirieno — I have some AutoHotkey code I use to move windows between two monitors. If the window is maximized: I restore it first, do the move, then maximize it again. This can take 1-2 seconds, but it works. Email my "deanhill1971" Gmail account if this sounds useful to yout.

Comment: @Dean: that's exactly the kind of code I've written for myself.  A normalised window will jump from monitor to monitor in an instant, but restore-move-maximise being a second or so is still too slow (not least because I have to make the window transparent before even doing the R-Mv-Mx process).  But thank you for the offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User **Lexikos** shows how to do it with a DLL call to GetWindowPlacement:

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-172836.html#172836

```
hwnd := WinExist("Untitled - Notepad")
WinGetPos, mX, mY
WinGetNormalPos(hwnd, x, y, w, h)
MsgBox Pos:`nx: %mX%`ny: %mY%`n`nNormalPos:`nx: %x%`ny: %y%`nw: %w%`nh: %h%

WinGetNormalPos(hwnd, ByRef x, ByRef y, ByRef w="", ByRef h="")
{
    VarSetCapacity(wp, 44), NumPut(44, wp)
    DllCall("GetWindowPlacement", "uint", hwnd, "uint", &wp)
    x := NumGet(wp, 28, "int")
    y := NumGet(wp, 32, "int")
    w := NumGet(wp, 36, "int") - x
    h := NumGet(wp, 40, "int") - y
}
```

Comment: This is spot on and works for getting the normalised position for a maximised window.  Good find!  Now I (maybe) need to work out how to *set* these values!..